# MongoDB Find function not returning even if exists

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I think I may have the syntax wrong with this find function as even if a document doesnt exist it still says there is a 'docs' but if the document exists the 'docs' which should be the record just returns empty??

function:

```
  addRefund : (refundCalc, callback) => {
    order_number = refundCalc.refundDetails.customer_details.order.order_number;
    console.log('TYPE OF ORDER NUMBER' + typeof order_number)
    dbconnect.createConnection()
    refund.find({order_number: order_number}, (err, docs) => {
        if (docs) {
            console.log('docss!!!!!!!!!!!!!' + docs[0])
            console.log('calling within error!!!!!!')
            let notStored = {"refundDocStored" : "False"}
            callback(notStored)
            dbconnect.closeConnection();
        }
```

and then my schema, this is where I may have things wrong, perhaps its not properly looking for the order number i dont know -

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5c7835dabffecf7f4be8ae69"
},
"refundDetails": {
    "refund": {
        "shipping": {
            "amount": 10,
            "tax": 0,
            "maximum_refundable": 10
        },
        "refund_line_items": [
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "line_item_id": 1835202838591,
                "location_id": null,
                "restock_type": "no_restock",
                "price": "15.44",
                "subtotal": "15.44",
                "total_tax": "0.00",
                "discounted_price": "15.44",
                "discounted_total_price": "15.44",
                "total_cart_discount_amount": "0.00"
            }
        ],
        "transactions": []
    },
    "customer_details": [
        {
            "order": {
                "customer_name": "Dale grant",
                "customer_email": "dalebradleygrant@yahoo.co.uk",
                "order_id": 791421321279,
                "order_number": 1025,
                "order_date": "2019-02-28T14:21:59-05:00",
                "total_price": "25.44",
                "subtotal_price": "15.44",
                "shipping_price": "10.00",
                "total_tax": "0.00",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 1835202838591,
                        "variant_id": 7051095769151,
                        "title": "Womens Summer Black Camis Dress",
                        "name": "Womens Summer Black Camis Dress - Black / S",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "price": "15.44",
                        "product_id": 561553309759
                    }
                ],
                "image_links": [
                    {
                        "product_id": 561553309759,
                        "image_src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0013/6688/4415/products/product-image-389399624.jpg?v=1521568884",
                        "varrient_id": []
                    },
                    {
                        "product_id": 561553309759,
                        "image_src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0013/6688/4415/products/product-image-389399629.jpg?v=1521568888",
                        "varrient_id": [
                            7051095769151,
                            7051095834687,
                            7051095867455,
                            7051095900223
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "fullfillmentText": "Hi, Please find your order details below:"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"domain": "chatbotdemo.myshopify.com",
"__v": 0
```

}

any help would be amazing.. really stuck on this one!

thanks.

Comment: I think it might be because of the `order_number` is nested inside `customer_details: [{ order: .... }]`. that's might be the reason it cannot find the `order_number` because it's not on the top layer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using with toArray function

```
addRefund : (refundCalc, callback) => {
    order_number = refundCalc.refundDetails.customer_details.order.order_number;
    console.log('TYPE OF ORDER NUMBER' + typeof order_number)
    dbconnect.createConnection()
    refund.find({order_number: order_number}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if (docs) {
            console.log('docss!!!!!!!!!!!!!' + docs[0])
            console.log('calling within error!!!!!!')
            let notStored = {"refundDocStored" : "False"}
            callback(notStored)
            dbconnect.closeConnection();
        }})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using dot notation to access embeded array

```
addRefund : (refundCalc, callback) => {
order_number = refundCalc.refundDetails.customer_details.order.order_number;
console.log('TYPE OF ORDER NUMBER' + typeof order_number)
dbconnect.createConnection()
refund.find({customer_details.order.order_number: order_number}, (err, docs) => {
    if (docs) {
        console.log('docss!!!!!!!!!!!!!' + docs[0])
        console.log('calling within error!!!!!!')
        let notStored = {"refundDocStored" : "False"}
        callback(notStored)
        dbconnect.closeConnection();
    }
```